# How to make stream pipeline pubsub to datastore with python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to post json file to pubsub and write to datastore with cloud Dataflow in streaming process.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import apache_beam as beam
import json
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2
from apache_beam import window
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import WriteToDatastore
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper

class EntityWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, namespace, kind, ancestor):
        self._namespace = namespace
        self._kind = kind
        self._ancestor = ancestor

    def make_entity(self, content):
        entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
        if self._namespace is not None:
            entity.key.partition_id.namespace_id = self._namespace

        datastore_helper.add_key_path(entity.key, self._kind, self._ancestor, self._kind, str(uuid.uuid4()))

        datastore_helper.add_properties(entity, {"content": unicode(content)})
        return entity

pipeline_options = {
    'project': PROJECT,
    'staging_location': STAGING_LOCATION,
    'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
    'job_name': JOB_NAME,
    'temp_location': TEMP_LOCATION,
    'streaming': True}

options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)

def run():
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    def parse_pubsub(line):
        record = json.loads(line)
        return record

    (p | "Read from PubSub" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC)
    | "PubSub message to Python object" >> beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
    | "Windowing" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10))
    | "create entity" >> beam.Map(EntityWrapper(namespace=NAMESPACE, kind=KIND, ancestor=None).make_entity)
    | "write to DataStore" >> WriteToDatastore(PROJECT))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

When I run this code on google cloud shell, it is able to run and make pipeline such like this.

[image: Pipeline]

But, when I post json to pubsub, it doesn't work.

the error message is below.

```
JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -30: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 134, in _execute
    response = task()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 169, in <lambda>
    self._execute(lambda: worker.do_instruction(work), work)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 215, in do_instruction
    request.instruction_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 237, in process_bundle
    processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 299, in process_bundle
    input_op.process_encoded(data.data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 120, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 166, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    def output(self, windowed_value, output_index=0):
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 167, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
    cython.cast(Receiver, self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 87, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 387, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 589, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 595, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 612, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 593, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 363, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
    output_processor.process_outputs(
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 698, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 87, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 387, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 589, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 595, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 612, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 593, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 472, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process
    self._invoke_per_window(
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 522, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_per_window
    output_processor.process_outputs(
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 659, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    def process_outputs(self, windowed_input_element, results):
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 698, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 87, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.receive
    cython.cast(Operation, consumer).process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 387, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    with self.scoped_process_state:
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 388, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
    self.dofn_receiver.receive(o)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 589, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
    self.process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 595, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 612, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 593, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
    self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 364, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
    windowed_value, self.process_method(windowed_value.value))
File "/home/shinya_yaginuma/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 1035, in <lambda>
File "pubsub_to_datastore.py", line 21, in make_entity
NameError: global name 'entity_pb2' is not defined

        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.fn.control.RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.finish(RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.java:274)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:83)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:101)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:136)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I check the all libraris are installed.
So, I can't understand why the error occur.

Regards,

Comment: We need more details: The json you're posting and the errors you are getting, source code, etc

Comment: Sorry, I add error mesage.

Comment: Looks like the library entity_pb2 isnt installed. It probably has to do with the path that you are running things from--your PWD

Comment: @Mars the environment is in GCP Dataflow, and it isn't directly modifiable from the user.

Comment: Also I am also having this error, on a much simpler Dataflow. My job runs without error using DirectRunner though. Super strange.

Comment: @jStaff So I looked into it a bit, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

So your imports are working fine, hence the error occurring when you make the pubsub, not on DF creation. However, entity_pb2 is disappearing when your make_entity actually gets called!

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq), you need the import on the worker that actually gets used, or you can make your imports persistent. Try saving your main session:

```
pipeline_options = {
    'project': PROJECT,
    'staging_location': STAGING_LOCATION,
    'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
    'job_name': JOB_NAME,
    'temp_location': TEMP_LOCATION,
    'streaming': True,
    'save_main_session': True} #
```